# Customers decrease with price increase: find the maximum price before no customers can afford candies.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the price of the candies is $\$10$ per box, there will be $100$ boxes sold. For each $\$1$ increase in price, $5\%$ of the customers no longer can afford candies. What is the maximum price that can be charged before no customers can afford candies?

Comment: Question was changed so now there's some work involved. The question remains though, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints (as a guided exercises):**

1. How many costumers do we have in the beginning ?
2. Denote the above number as $x$. If the price has increased by
   $d$, how many costumers are there as a function of $x$ and $d$
   ?
3. What is the maximal $d$ such that the number of costumers after
   the price increase is still positive ?
4. Take the above maximal $d$, how many coustemers can afford the
   box when the starting price have increased by $d+1$ ?